# Cast to custom class type in PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel.

Due to it being MVC, I am passing a model (an object) of a certain class type into the view.

Of course, inside my view... it has no idea what the controller has pushed out when i'm developing, so I lose my typeahead on my ViewModels...

I tried doing something like this:

```
(TimesheetViewModel)$Model;
```

But unfortunately that doesn't work...

What I end up having to do is declare a `$Model = new TimesheetViewModel();` just to help me develop the page and then get rid of it at the end. It's dumb... Any good ways of helping out my typeahead?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using PHP doc:
At the beginning of the view:

```
<?php
/* @var $model TimesheetViewModel */
?>
```

Comment: + for the answer, but this was ultimately an IDE *issue* and had nothing to do with PHP or Laravel.

Comment: here it's also important to mention that not all IDE support this phpdoc notation